# Sonar: Disable XML external entity (XXE) processing

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am using javax.xml.validation.Validator to validate my xml as below

```java
        private final Validator validator;
        ...

        SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        factory.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
        factory.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA, "");
        Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File(getResource(path)));
        validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
        validator.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA, "");
```

Any idea why sonar says this code is noncompliant?

Comment: In IntelliJ I did not face this issue for Sonar plugin, I face issue if setFeature is used.

Answer (score 5):

You have to set `XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD` and `XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA` to "".

Below code will not give any violation with SonarLint and SonarQube.

```
private Validator validator;
...
    
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File(getResource(path)));
validator = schema.newValidator();
validator.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
validator.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA, "");
```

Then, Block external entities where you are validating it.
For example, If you are using STAX parser. Then set `XMLInputFactory.IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES` and `XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD` to `False`.

```
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
factory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES, Boolean.FALSE);
factory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD, Boolean.FALSE);
validator.validate(new StAXSource(factory.createXMLStreamReader(inputStream)));
```

If you are using sonarLint then clean your caches by deleting target folder of the project.

For more info:
https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2755