# Vulnerability due to TransformerFactory

Tags: java

I am getting vulnerability issue due to below code:

StreamSource ss=new StreamSource(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(template));

Transformer ts=TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(ss);

I am facing vulnerability issue in sonarqube for 2nd line(Disable access to external entities in XML parsing).
Can anyone please help me to resolve this vulnerability issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sonar: Disable XML external entity (XXE) processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63501145/sonar-disable-xml-external-entity-xxe-processing)

Comment: Could you please suggest how to do this for TransformerFactory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation of TransformerFactory.setFeature](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#setFeature(java.lang.String,boolean)) says:

> All implementations are required to support the `XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING` feature.

So all you need to do is:

```
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
factory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
Transformer ts = factory.newTransformer(ss);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 1st issue got resolved. But, now I am facing "A malicious xslt could be provided to trigger remote code execution" vulnerability for the below code: Transformer ts= factory.newTransformer(ss); could you please suggest any resolution on this.

Comment: Use Class.getResource instead of ClassLoader.getResource.  And place the XSLT in the same package as your class, so it is unlikely to be shadowed (deliberately or accidentally) by another library.